# OS X Cocoa WebView looses focus and :hover function stops working

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I'm kinda battling with WebView. I'm having a menu popup with WebView in it and when I launch the app it works perfectly, mouse hovers and changes the cursor like in normal web browser. But when I leave the app opened few minutes and then go back to it. It looses its focus, so you have to click inside the WebView to enable scrolling again. And also it doesn't hover over the buttons or links (simple ). Even if I click inside the WebView it still doesn't change to hover cursor.

I've tried put this `[panel setInitialFirstResponder:self.webView];` inside the function that triggers every-time when popup opens. Didn't help, same effect as before.

And I really don't know what to try to solve the hover effect problem.

I'm on OS X 10.10.4 and here is what I'm trying to approach.

[image: Design]

Comment: Have you tried to call `makeFirstResponder:` on the panel and passing the WebView as the parameter?

Comment: Actually I have rewritten the whole application because I couldnt make it work as it was.